# Edit file on SFTP server

Tags: php, ssh, sftp

i have written a script that takes the users input from an textarea and puts it in a text file. It also checks if the users piece of text already exists in the text file, in that case it does not write to the file (to prevent duplicate entries).
In my code below, the file in question is 'textfile.txt'. Instead of that one i want to edit a file on a SFTP server. I've read something about ssh2_sftp but i didn't understand how to use it. Please help me!

Also, is there any security risk to let people edit a text file on a server using the code below? (except spamming and the file getting ridicously large, as i am using a CAPTCHA for the input form).

Thank you!

```
<?
$text = $_POST['update'];
$handle = file_get_contents("textfile.txt",NULL); 
$text=str_replace(",","",$text); 
$text=explode(" ",$text); 
$c=0; 
foreach($text as $y){ 
if (stristr($handle,"$text[$c]")) $b[]= 'yes'; 
else $b[]='no'; 
$c++; 
} 
echo $handle; 
if (in_array("no",$b)) /*här */if($_POST['Submit']){
$open = fopen("textfile.txt","a+");
$text = $_POST['update'];
fwrite($open, "".$text."\n");
fclose($open);
echo "<br/><br/><br/>".$text." has been saved."; 
foreach($file as $text) {
echo $text."<br />";
}
}else{    
} 
else echo '<br/><br/>Thats already in there.'; 
?>
```

Comment: I know it's not related but do yourself a favor and don't use short php tags...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Unless you're sanitizing how the content of the file is shown (from what I see, you're using an `echo $handle;` to display it), then a person could submit crafted HTML and create an XSS attack.

You might want to consider using [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) on the input data to help prevent this.

Also, a DOS attack could be launched fairly easily because of the usage of `file_get_contents` on a file of unknown size.  This can be lessened by simply looping through the file line-by-line or by putting a limit on how long the user submitted text can be.  This attack isn't likely as serious because you're using CAPTCHA which will slow down most users from submitting text rapidly, but if `file_get_contents()` is called without usage of CAPTCHA (say, for viewing the file's contents) then you'll still have a problem.

**Edit:** I rewrote most of your code snippet for you and added lots of comments.  Hopefully you can pick up a few tips and tricks from it and gain a better understanding of best programming practices.  (I haven't tried running the code, but it should work fine.  Make modifications to it as needed.)
http://pastebin.com/W1EQ3fSm

Comment: Wow, thank you! I think i've understood all parts of the code you wrote. I have two questions;

_1._ How can i make it so that the part of the code that checks the file for the string only checks whole words/lines? So that you can have **ExampleText** in the text file, and still submit **ExampleLine** to the file? Right now it finds "Example" and aborts.

_2._ As in my question above, how can i add to a text file on a SFTP server?

      Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)...

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
$sftp->put('textfile.txt', $sftp->get('textfile.txt') . $_POST['update']."\n");
?>
```